# Views - Filtering view results by current user profile field

Tags: views

I have been trying to do this last couple of days but no luck.

Every user have a custom field (favorite_car) which is taxonomy and there is different terms ('Audi','Bmw' etc).

I have also content type 'Cars' which had also a custom field (favorite_car).

I need to display only the results, that user have selected. 
If user have a custom field selected to 'Bmw', view need to return only nodes which have a favorite_car field set to 'Bmw'.

I think that there is a way to do this in drupal 7. Every kind of help is welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter contents on their term_reference_field by the field_value of a term_reference_field of the current_user:

So we go:

- Create a content_view
- Create a relationship with "favorite_car"
- Create a relationship with "term from favorite_car"
- Create contextual filter user:uid with provide default_value: user_id from logged in user and the relationship favorite_car

This works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the answer to [Add Taxonomy Term automatically based on term from user's account](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77571/add-taxonomy-term-automatically-based-on-term-from-users-account)

Replace the references to "state of residence" with "favorite car" and references to "forum postings view" with "car listings view".