# Matching user accounts in views with taxonomy

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

In user accounts we have two Term fields that use the same taxonomy vocabulary. For example, the user profile has *I need* and a *I have* fields.

For example User A has a blue crayon but wants a red one.

```
- I have 
-- X Blue Crayon
-- - Red Crayon
-- - Green Crayon
- I want 
-- - Blue Crayon
-- X Red Crayon
-- - Green Crayon
```

I would like to craft a view that, based on User A's desire marked want, finds all users that have Red Crayon they want to lend.

Ideally, I'd like to auto populate this contextual filter with what the logged in user has specified. For example in this situation, I want to populate *When the filter value is not in the URL*'s *Provide Default Value* field with the term_id of Red Crayon. Thus, listing everyone with ready to lend a red crayon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the create view wizard, you need to choose, show "Users."

In the filters section you'll create a filter for "I want" whose value is set via PHP to grab the current users choice for "I have." You'll need the [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module for this.

Comment: What about contextual filter? Is there a way to populate this based on the logged in user's profile?

Comment: You are trying to populate the value of a filter with a value from another field. That doesn't seem doable to me via a contextual filter.

Comment: Upon further research, [here is a recipe](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77571/add-taxonomy-term-automatically-based-on-term-from-users-account) that uses the [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module to achieve what you are after... using contextual arguments.